# ¿Por qué este div no se alinea totalmente?

Tags: html5, css3, css-grid-layout

Mi problema es que el div se empieza a imprimir en pantalla a partir del centro de la pagina y lo que yo quiero es que el div alineé su centro con el centro de la pagina, es decir, gráficamente hablando que la linea vertical blanca que se forma entre los cuadros celestes quede en el centro de la pagina ¿Cómo lo ajusto?

```css
body {
width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #5DADE2;
  text-align: center;
}

 #centrar {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mycss.css">
    <title>Pruebas</title>
</head>
<body> <!-- s,m,lg,xl-->
    <div id="centrar">
        <div class="container">
            <article class="item">1</article>
            <article class="item">2</article>
            <article class="item">3</article>
            <article class="item">4</article>
            <article class="item">5</article>
            <article class="item">6</article>
            <article class="item">7</article>
            <article class="item">8</article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<script src="Myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
width: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  display: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #5DADE2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mycss.css">
    <title>Pruebas</title>
</head>
<body> <!-- s,m,lg,xl-->
    <div id="centrar">
        <div class="container">
            <article class="item">1</article>
            <article class="item">2</article>
            <article class="item">3</article>
            <article class="item">4</article>
            <article class="item">5</article>
            <article class="item">6</article>
            <article class="item">7</article>
            <article class="item">8</article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<script src="Myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Lo único que hice fue usar la propiedad `justify-content` . [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout) te dejo más información.